# How to redirect if login is successful?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect, navigation, cookie-httponly

How to redirect from login page if login is successful? I'm using HTTPOnly Cookie for user authentication.
With the code below i'm able to redirect to home page if user logs in with their credentials. Nevertheless, if the user enters incorrect username or password, the page navigates to home page but user isn't logged in. How can I make page navigate only when credentials are correct and avoid navigating to home page if credentials are incorrect?

**Login.jsx**

```
function Login({ onUpdateUser }) {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    username: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function handleChange(e) {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/login", {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    })
     .then((r) => {
        if (!r.ok) throw Error("Incorrect username or password!")
        .then(navigate('/login'))
      })
      .then((user) => onUpdateUser(user))
      .then(navigate('/'))
  }
```

Comment: I don't get it why you want to redirect user to login page if the password and username is incorrect because the user would most probably be present on login page by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if condition` part in `.then` seems fishy.

I think it should be like

```js
.then((r) => {
        if (!r.ok){
          throw Error("Incorrect username or password!")
        }else{
          // username and email are true and accepted so navigate to "/"
          navigate('/')
        }
      })
.then((user) => onUpdateUser(user))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this

```
.then(()=> navigate('Home'))
```

instead of

```
.then(navigate('/login'))
```

Answer (score -1):

your use of `promise... then...` doesn't seem right.

```
.then(navigate('/login'))
```

should be

```
.then(()=> navigate('/login'))
```